# How do I get IF ELSE to return an image?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this if else script that returns either "Correct" or "Incorrect"

How do I get it to return an image instead of text?

Images I wish to use are: 
Correct: http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png
Incorrect: http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/thumbs-down.png

```
What is 1 + 1?<br>

Answer:&nbsp;<input type="text" length="3" id="ANSWER1A">
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Q1A()">

<script language="javascript">
    function Q1A()
    {
        var A = document.getElementById("ANSWER1A").value;
        var A;
        if (A == '2') {
        R = "CORRECT";
    } else {
        R = "INCORRECT";
    } 
document.getElementById("RETURN1A").innerHTML = R;
    }
</script>

<p id="RETURN1A">
```

Comment: you can return an img tag with the src set to the respective images you want to use. `R = '<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png"/>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What is 1 + 1?<br>

Answer:&nbsp;<input type="text" length="3" id="ANSWER1A">
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Q1A()">

<script language="javascript">
    function Q1A()
    {
        var A = document.getElementById("ANSWER1A").value;
        var A;
        if (A == '2') {
        R = "http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png";
    } else {
        R = "http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/thumbs-down.png";
    } 
document.getElementById("RETURN1A").src = R;
    }
</script>

<img id="RETURN1A">
```

```html
What is 1 + 1?<br>

Answer:&nbsp;<input type="text" length="3" id="ANSWER1A">
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Q1A()">

<script language="javascript">
    function Q1A()
    {
        var A = document.getElementById("ANSWER1A").value;
        var A;
        if (A == '2') {
        R = "http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png";
    } else {
        R = "http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/thumbs-down.png";
    } 
document.getElementById("RETURN1A").src = R;
    }
</script>

<img id="RETURN1A">
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you changed?

Comment: changed `<p>` tag to `<img>` tag and set the `src` attribute using  `document.getElementById("RETURN1A").src = R;`